# How to number rows 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2 in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking to number the rows of my output with four 1’s, then four 2’s etc etc regardless of the value in the rows. My data is sorted by week so I am basically trying to group the weeks into groups of four.

I have tried looking at `row_number()` but can’t figure out how to do this.
Any help appreciated.

Desired output:

| Week Code | Revenue | Grouping |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FY23 W1 | £21,531 | 1 |
| FY23 W2 | £4,927 | 1 |
| FY23 W3 | £22,651 | 1 |
| FY23 W4 | £5,612 | 1 |
| FY23 W5 | £16,307 | 2 |
| FY23 W6 | £11,824 | 2 |
| FY23 W7 | £15,840 | 2 |
| FY23 W8 | £37,761 | 2 |
| FY23 W9 | £4,603 | 3 |
| FY23 W10 | £36,549 | 3 |
| FY23 W11 | £37,566 | 3 |
| FY23 W12 | £29,117 | 3 |
| FY23 W13 | £41,589 | 4 |
| FY23 W14 | £2,910 | 4 |
| FY23 W15 | £40,596 | 4 |
| FY23 W16 | £3,611 | 4 |
| FY23 W17 | £27,731 | 5 |
| FY23 W18 | £43,338 | 5 |
| FY23 W19 | £22,971 | 5 |
| FY23 W20 | £42,099 | 5 |
| FY23 W21 | £40,962 | 6 |
| FY23 W22 | £15,621 | 6 |
| FY23 W23 | £16,422 | 6 |
| FY23 W24 | £44,012 | 6 |

Comment: Post the *actual* table schema and test data in the question as text. Instead of trying to calculate row numbers on the week code you may be able to partition by month on the date field the week code came from

Comment: You may be able to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC('month',date_field) ORDER BY WeekCode)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select WeekCode, Revenue, 1 + (row_number() over (order by WeekCode) - 1) / 4 from Data
```

Comment: I appreciate how quick, brief and close this answer was, but it's demonstrably wrong due to how such week codes sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
select (rn/4)+1-if (rn%4)=0 then 1 else 0 end if Grouping,* from (select  row_number() over(order by id desc) rn ,WeekCode,Revenue from my_table order by id desc)foo
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) window function, but don't forget you also need an adequate [collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#ICU-CUSTOM-COLLATIONS) for that to work properly with your week codes: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mzE88XGy)

```
CREATE COLLATION num_ignore_punct 
  (provider = icu, locale = 'und-u-ka-shifted-kn');

SELECT "WeekCode", 
       "Revenue", 
       ceil(row_number()OVER(ORDER BY "WeekCode" COLLATE num_ignore_punct)/4.) "Grouping"
FROM my_table;
```

| WeekCode | Revenue | Grouping |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FY23 W1 | 21531 | 1 |
| FY23 W2 | 4927 | 1 |
| FY23 W3 | 22651 | 1 |
| FY23 W4 | 5612 | 1 |
| FY23 W5 | 16307 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| FY23 W24 | 44012 | 6 |

You also need to keep in mind that [mixed-case identifiers require double-quoting in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS), otherwise they get folded to lowercase, which can lead to surprising mismatches.

There are plenty [mathematical](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html) tricks based on modulo 4 that'll get you a single increment every 4 steps. I like `ceil(x/4.)` because it does just two things. `(3+x)/4` is *also* nice. `1+(x-1)/4` is *almost* as nice. [Difference](https://dbfiddle.uk/pVH3dqHi) is rather negligible.

---

If you don't use a collation that treats digits as numbers, default will sort 10-19 between 1 and 2:

```
select "WeekCode", "Revenue", 1 + (row_number() over (order by "WeekCode") - 1) / 4 from my_table
```

| WeekCode | Revenue | ?column? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FY23 W1 | 21531 | 1 |
| FY23 W10 | 36549 | 1 |
| FY23 W11 | 37566 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| FY23 W19 | 22971 | 3 |
| FY23 W2 | 4927 | 3 |
| FY23 W20 | 42099 | 4 |